# How do you access a file mapped in manifest.json in an html file?

Tags: html, reactjs, manifest.json

So I have a generated manifest file as follows,

```
{
  "0.0eaa8ffc6b248ee016ed.bundle.js": "test/public/dist/0.0eaa8ffc6b248ee016ed.bundle.js",
  "1.7e194c6ac39e9447bead.bundle.js": "test/public/dist/1.7e194c6ac39e9447bead.bundle.js",
  "2.20766d436d451349eca2.bundle.js": "test/public/dist/2.20766d436d451349eca2.bundle.js",
  "index.js": "site/public/dist/index.96a6be838d583dae3962.bundle.js",
}
```

I want to specify this index.js file hashed file in my index.html

```
<script src="test/public/dist/index.js"></script>
```

How do I access this file in my html file?

Comment: I tried  <script src="test/public/dist/manifest[index.js]"></script> as well. It still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should look for something similar to [this Webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to achieve that purpose.

You should never manual import the output file with has hash in name.